# Wrong casting to int32 ? expecting uint16 instead?

Tags: python, numpy, casting

Why the in the second case numpy does wrong casting to **int32** ??
I have to use second case, because i use a variable..

```
In [24]: np.zeros(10,dtype=np.uint16) - 1
Out[24]: array([65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535], dtype=uint16)



In [23]: np.zeros(10,dtype=np.uint16) + (-1)
Out[23]: array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], dtype=int32)
```

---

```
In [26]: np.zeros(10,dtype=np.uint16) + np.uint16(-1)
Out[26]: array([65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535, 65535], dtype=uint16)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a *wrong* casting, `numpy` is trying to find the smallest type that can handle all the possible results.

You can find out what type the result is going to be with [`np.result_type`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html#numpy.result_type):

```
np.result_type(np.uint16, -1)

>>> int32

np.result_type(np.uint16, 1)

>>> uint16
```

With `np.zeros(10,dtype=np.uint16) + np.uint16(-1)`, the result will be a `uint16`, and this is what you need to do to force an unsigned result. Otherwise, `numpy` will assume that the result must be cast to handle negative values.